# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I am getting below error when I am trying to update a table with a field(datetime)

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[2007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '02-27-2017 16:37' for column lastupated

My PHP code uses PDO

```
$lastupdated = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
$run = $conn->prepare($sql);
$run->bindParam(':lastupdated', $lastupdated, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

the SQL 
the lastupdated, datatype is `datetime`

Existing data

[image]

Comment: The dateformat is clearly wrong. Correct would be year-month-day

Comment: Use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ?

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to format date like `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` in order to work with MySQL datetime field.

i.e. :

```
$lastupdated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) :

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html): Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts.  But the real issue is his ordering of the date parts.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. Didn't know that.

Comment: Neither did I.  And I'm glad nobody actually uses `2017@02@28` as a date literal :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and Jazz thanks, both of you, for the help, it worked.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Of course. I used to write date like 2017/02/28. This will be usefull !

Comment: You're welcome @user580950. Thanks for validate my answer if it solved your question. Good luck. = )