# Change date format to save it in database by Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm New in Laravel;

I'm Using Data Packer Jquery and it output like this format:

14-Aug-2019

I tray to save it in database by this code:

```
if ($request -> isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request -> all();
        $course = new Courses;
        $course -> start_date = $data['start_date'];
        $course -> save();
        return redirect('/admin/courses');
    }
```

But i found this error:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '14-Aug-2019' for column 'start_date' at row 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490101/invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value)  Please take a look here, it should be helpful to you :)

Comment: try `$course->start_date = new \Carbon\Carbon($data['start_date']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL expects date to be like `2019-08-14` and you are trying to save `14-Aug-2019`. So you are getting the error. You can solve it either by sending the exact formatted date from the front end or parse it in the back end.

Send `Y-m-d` value from the datepicker

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
});
```

It will send date like `2019-08-14` and you can save it directly.

If you want to use format like `14-Aug-2019` then you have to parse it using Carbon so that you can save it in the database.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = '14-Aug-2019';
$d = Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d'); //return date 2019-08-14
```

> Cast your `start_date` as a date in your model. It will help you to format it anyway you want.

```
class Courses extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['start_date'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man it work without "Cast start_date as a date in model"

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will for for you

```
    if ($request -> isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request -> all();
        $course = new Courses;
        $course -> start_date = STR_TO_DATE($data['start_date'], '%d-%M-%Y');
        $course -> save();
        return redirect('/admin/courses');
    }
```

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` is not a php function.